Warning: Undefined array key "login"
<?php 
if (true == $_SESSION['login']) {
                    echo "HELLO..! Welcome";
                }else{
                    echo "HELLO..! Please Log-in";
}
?>  

the program was running but before filling up the login form.
Warning: Undefined array key "login"  this error appeared. After Submitting This error does not display.

If there's a doubt whether the session variable exists at this point in the code, then you must check it using something like isset() before using it.

this variable I'm using this only for my Condition meets purpose.

Check if a variable is undefined in PHP

Hi you can try this maybe it works Let me know if it worked
<?php 
if (isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login'] == true) {
    echo "HELLO..! Welcome";
} else {
    echo "HELLO..! Please Log-in";
}
?> 


It is not helpful to Stack Overflow to answer new questions with advice that has been on Stack Overflow for decades.  I understand that you don't yet have the privilege to close duplicates questions, but if you are unable to discern good questions from bad questions, please avoid answering questions until they are at least a day old.  When you answer a duplicate question, the system cannot automatically delete the unwanted page.  If you remove this answer, the Roomba will be able to purge this page in a few days without needing humans to do so manually.
